# Local-only Automator service (not on iCloud)

Tags: automator

I do not want to have the services on iCloud, but instead just local to Mac. Here's what the Automator dialog displays.

[image]

How can it be done?

Comment: What's stopping you from saving it into a local directory?

Comment: what's _allowing_ me to do that .. it is annotated as `iCloud`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deselect Automator In iCloud System Preferences

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply click on any of the folder under Recent Places. You can also native to a local directory of your choosing. If you select a local directory, the service won't be saved in iCloud storage.

You need not turn disable iCloud for Automator for saving the service locally.

Comment: ok but i _never_ want iCloud for Automator and have thus accepted the other answer.  but i'll upvote as potentially useful for someone else.